# How to change the position of a plugin option menu in WordPress Dashboard

Tags: wordpress

I try to rearrange the order of menus in Dashboard in WordPress without using a plugin.

I changed the order of basic menus such as "Posts", "Pages", "Comments"... But I have been struggling to move the plugin menu "**All in One SEO**" which is on the second position in Dashboard.

[image]

Is there a way to move it under Settings menu?

If it's not easy to change the order of this plugin option menu, I would like to remove it from Dashboard menu. I tried to use the following code, which does not work:

```
remove_menu_page('admin.php?page=all-in-one-seo-pack/aioseop_class.php');
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can demote the ALL IN ONE SEO plugin's menu to bottom using this setting they have there:

"Go to **General Settings** in All in One SEO Pack, scroll down to the **Display Settings** box and you will see the checkboxes there where you can disable AIOSEOP on the Admin Bar and demote the side menu item to the bottom."

Source: Plugin Author

See Screenshot showing the actual setting there: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ga8JW.jpg

Comment: Thank you very much. I just changed the option^^